# Interaction pop view controller from top to bottom swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, user-interaction

I am using this code to animate view controller with scale transition-

```
if (self.isPresenting) {
    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];
    [toVC.view setAlpha:0];
    CGAffineTransform xForm = toVC.view.transform;
    toVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(xForm, 1.0f, 0.8f);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                     animations:^{
                         [toVC.view setAlpha:1];
                         toVC.view.transform =
                         CGAffineTransformScale(xForm, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                         fromVC.view.transform =
                         CGAffineTransformScale(fromVC.view.transform, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                     }];
}
else {

    [containerView addSubview:toVC.view];
    [containerView addSubview:fromVC.view];

    CGAffineTransform xForm = toVC.view.transform;
    toVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(toVC.view.transform, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                     animations:^{
                         [fromVC.view setAlpha:0];
                         fromVC.view.transform =
                         CGAffineTransformScale(xForm, 0.7f, 0.7f);
                         toVC.view.transform =
                         CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                     }];
}
```

Its working perfect when present and dismiss view (on back button click) But i need to do is when user drag view from top to bottom then also it should dismiss the view controller.

any help how can i add this ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the same code in target method of swipe gesture?

Comment: Yes i tried adding pan gesture but not success to do with smooth animation.